# How to generate dagger's (v1) object graph (*.dot) in gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, graphviz, dagger, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is there a way to generate the .dot files for GraphViz to see the DAG using dagger 1 in gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake. The graphs (*.dot) are automatically generated by dagger's compiler. I was looking at the wrong folders and was running the find command wrong.

It's generated in ./app/build/generated/source/apt/*

Here's the find command for mac: find . -name "*.dot"